# grunt is not recognized

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, gruntjs

I am new to grunt and I'm using:

- Node: 6.9.2
- npm: 3.10.9
- OS: Windows 7

When I run the following command to install grunt:

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

I get this error message:

> `grunt is not recognized as internal or external command.`

Looking forward for any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirm your PATH in your environment variables settings. You need to have an entry there where the global node binaries are.

you can check to see if C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm contains grunt (grunt.cmd).

If you cannot find grunt anywhere on your machine, you need to verify that node and npm are both installed correctly, and retry installing grunt, remember that you may need a terminal session with administrator rights in order to install it correctly.

To edit enviroment variables on Windows 7

Open Control Panel
Click System & Security
Click System
Choose Advanced System Settings on the sidebar
In the Advanced Pane of the windows, click the Environment Variables button in the bottom right corner.
You should find "PATH" in the list
append it's value with your path, separate paths with a ;

Comment: I do not have AppData folder in my C:\Users\Username folder

Comment: Now I can see grunt.cmd in the path you have specified. " C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm". But is not exist in path. Can I edit the path manually?

Comment: you can try %AppData% in an explorer, or switch on "Hidden Items" in the view pane of explorer.

Comment: Yes, AppData folder was hidden. Now I can see grunt.cmd file. How can I add it to path?

Comment: yes, open up Environment Variables from your System  Settings. You can search for Environment I believe and it should pop up. Or you will find them under Advanced System Settings.

Comment: Yes, I found the Environment variables pop up. I have user variables and system variables.In user variable I can see PATH.

Comment: append the path with the path to your node binaries, and re-open your command terminal. grunt should fire. See my updated answer.

Comment: PATH  :   C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm ?? or C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\grunt.cmd ??

Comment: the first one, and you need to make sure that the rest of the path string is kept intact.

Comment: PATH is a list of directories that has their contents in the scope of a session. As if their contents reside in the current directory, hence no need for specifying the complete path to the commands.

Comment: I have added ";" after the current path and then C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm  then opened command prompt and ran grunt --help. still same error :(

Comment: When I type PATH in command prompt, it is showing me the PATH value but it doesn't contain the new path value that I have added.

Comment: You could try typing this in the command prompt: set PATH=%PATH%;%APPDATA%\npm
Then retrying the grunt command

Comment: If the path isn't updated, you need to go back to the environment variables window and re-edit it. Make sure you save it and exit the window before opening a new terminal. See if there is a path in the System section as well.

Comment: I did set PATH=%PATH%;%APPDATA%\npm and then I typed PATH in command prompt to see the updated PATH. It consists the new grunt path for 2 times as "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm".

Comment: I deleted from manual path setting and again did set PATH=%PATH%;%APPDATA%\npm. Now I can see single grunt path. Now when I run grunt --help it is showing error as "If you are seeing this information, grunt is not installed properly and go to grunt website for more ifno."

Comment: Hey Its working now :). Thank you so much for your time and patience :)